# Differences between purposes of inode, fork and extended file attribute?

Tags: filesystems

1. I was wondering  what differences
   are between [inode](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode&ei=45P2TYKhH4Tm0QHE6cXbBA&usg=AFQjCNFS15lNcW09k9Cz2nvOs9Cb4EhxDA&sig2=3gX7tLVzYWR8PzUsTzCmFQ), [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28filesystem%29)
   and [extended file attribute](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes&ei=U5P2TdrBCcjl0QHs5tTrDA&usg=AFQjCNG2QtTG0SavhV3fm0d0p5Fedn1y3w&sig2=8iRN2W0TOwyaXe87K88BQA)?
2. All seem to me store attributes
   about a file. Are there differences
   between the attributes they store?
   Are these attributes they store
   called metadata of the file?
3. Are there differences between the
   file system types they can apply to?
4. Are they all not considered part of
   the content of a file?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Turbo: No. Should I feel flattered that my questions look like homework?

Comment: In short, `inode` stores the **basic** metadata of a file, pertaining to the file system. `fork`, for example in Windows, is used to additional data about data (for example, to store thumbnails of images). `xattr` is the additional attributes of a file (that is required additionally for other purposes like SELinux security contexts that can be modified by `chcon` command). There are some places where the names xattr and fork are interchangeably used; they just differ in their extensibility of their size. (This is how I have understood it)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  Fun one.

Interestingly I'm primarily aware of inodes in reference to Linux OSes, where forks and extended attributes are less common.  For Linux, an inode is essentially the file.  Logically it is just an identifier / a holder for the access control information and the pointer to the various data, but from the operating system's perspective it is a symbol that has a one-to-one relationship to everything thought of as the file.

A fork (a Windows and Mac filesystem concept as far as I'm aware) is essentially a place to store additional file data.  Think of it as a way to store additional data that doesn't show up when you use the default method for viewing the file(s) (e.g. cat / get-contents / ?)

Extended attributes are what you would traditionally think of as metadata.  This is free-form but tends to be limited in scope (in contrast a fork is free-form and not limited in scope, and an inode is heavily limited in scope and form).  You might use extended attributes to list an author, copyright date, source planet, GPS coordinates, hints about whose butt that is on the coffee table, etc.